# Eclipse CDT: How can I change background color of tooltip in editor?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using eclipse for coding C++ and Java. When declaration or definition is shown, background is black. It happens only in C++ srouce file. I dont have this problem while editing Java source files.

I have installed Eclipse Color Theme. I'm not able to find where i can set background color of this window. I have been searching in `General/Appearance/Colors and Fonts` and `C/C++/Editor/Syntax Coloring` without result.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem because I installed [this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme) plugin. I tried out the themes but when I decided on the original and swapped back to it the tool tips were broken in this fashion. Unfortunately the only way I managed to fix it was by "reinstalling" eclipse.

Comment: When i set theme, tooltip is shown ok. Uninstall of the plugin did not helped. Since I am not willing to reinstall Eclipse now, i'm going to find suitable theme. Thanks for you answerd, it helped.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. I know how you feel; I reinstalled eclipse because I got a new computer but otherwise would have tried to fix the theme.

Comment: I found [this theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=1656) that looks like eclipse

Comment: I ended by creating own theme. That bug is awkward.

Comment: Does that fix the problem? I found even with an okay dark theme the frames in eclipse are just too bright and I found it a bit jarring.

Comment: sourceHoverBackground is the value that determine background color of tooltip in C++ editor. It looks like if you choose Default, this value is set to black, instead of real default.

Answer (score 8):

Switching to a clean workspace might help but I found the curprit if you want to manually edit it. Look in:

```
[my workspace]/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs
```

for

```
sourceHoverBackgroundColor.SystemDefault=false
```

and make it "true". Restart Eclipse. Of course this assumes that your system default background colour is *not* black.

Comment: Definitely +1. I had the same weird problem after deinstalling the Color Theme Plugin, and this totally fixed it! Thank you @archxs!