# eclipse cdt - how to set the background color of the tooltips window in C/C++ editor window?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have the same problem as that described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320537/eclipse-cdt-how-can-i-change-background-color-of-tooltip-in-editor)

I am using Eclipse 3.5.2 with CDT and have not installed this [Color Theme Plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme). When I am editing C/C++ source files and placing the cursor over a defined method, the generated tooltip window shows a "black" background color so that I could not clearly see the text inside the tooltip window. I have tried to change settings in "C/C++/Editor/Syntax Coloring" preference but I have not found setting of background color for tooltip window.

The above post suggested that I may have to re-install the whole eclipse but this solution seems would cause many troubles to me. Does anyone know an easier solution for this apparently small problem.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full re-installation of eclipse may not be needed. However, it's worth cleaning up the workspace / project related settings. You can follow below steps:

1. Go to the workspace folder and remove `.metadata`
2. Go to the projects whichever you created under this workspace and
   remove, `.cproject` and `.project`
3. Now, start the eclipse from the scratch, you will see that all your
   color combination you set are gone ... it's ok
4. Install the color themes plugin; don't be afraid of it, it's really cool (it doesn't cause such issues for
   me);
5. Download a proper color theme preference file `.epf` ([here is
   mine](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=4318))
6. Store this `.epf` file inside your workspace directory; so that you
   know that this color theme is for this workspace; though you can
   store this anywhere
7. Go to File -> Import -> General -> Preferences and select this
   `.epf` file and install.
8. You will get the desired black background and grey text and the
   auto-complete options would be unaffected

You can also think of installing the full screen plugin for eclipse, for better visibility.

Comment: Too complicated and intrusive. There is a setting for just this color.

Answer (score 9):

The default UI prefs in CDT seems to be missing the "sourceHoverBackgroundColor" setting.

To fix this add a line like the following:

```
sourceHoverBackgroundColor=255,255,255
```

to the file

[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs

(be sure to back-up the file before you make changes to it!)

you'll need to get eclipse to re-read that file by restarting eclipse.

Comment: Actually I have since discovered that this can be done from the front-end. Go to Window->Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Source hover background. You will need to uncheck "System Default" as it incorrectly shows grey as the chosen colour.

Answer (score 7):

Change this color in the Eclipse preferences (Window/Prefernces menu). Good color is rgb=255,255,225 (this is default for Java), or choose your own.

[image]

Credits to assifm.